# Контекстное меню datagrid

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio

Добрый день.

У меня возникла проблема с контекстным меню в datagridview.
Конкретней: я создал меню для datagrid, которое вызывается при нажатии правой мыши, но данное событие происходит со второго раза и при этом решает в последующих нажатиях выбрать ячейку в datagrid, то есть меню вызывается, но действия по выбору ячейки в datagrid не происходит. А вот если уничтожать переменные контекстного меню после их работы, то выбор ячеек появляется, но само меню перестает вызываться.
Я слышал, что тут, может быть, замешаны контролы форм и их уровень приоритета. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Вызов меню

```
public void dataGridView2_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right == e.Button & e.Clicks == 1 & comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "CIM_Process")
            {
                RequestWMI_Process Call_ContextMenuCIM_Porcess = new RequestWMI_Process(this);
                Call_ContextMenuCIM_Porcess.Create_ContextMenuCIM();
            }
            else if (System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left != e.Button & e.Clicks > 1 & comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "CIM_Process")
            {
                RequestWMI_Process Call_ContextMenuCIM_Porcess = new RequestWMI_Process(this);
                Call_ContextMenuCIM_Porcess.ContextMenuCIM_Porcess(sender, e);
                dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected = true;
                dataGridView2.Focus();
            }
        }
```

Создание меню и вычисление индекса

```
public void Create_ContextMenuCIM()
        {
            ContextMenuStrip MenuGrid2 = new ContextMenuStrip();
            ToolStripMenuItem MenuGrid2Copy = new ToolStripMenuItem("Копировать");
            ToolStripMenuItem MenuGrid2Delet = new ToolStripMenuItem("Удалить");
            ToolStripMenuItem MenuGrid2Paste = new ToolStripMenuItem("Вставить");
            MenuGrid2.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { MenuGrid2Copy, MenuGrid2Delet, MenuGrid2Paste });
            Component.dataGridView2.ContextMenuStrip = MenuGrid2;
        }
        public void ContextMenuCIM_Porcess(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int IndexRowsGR2 = 0;
            System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.HitTestInfo hittestinfo = Component.dataGridView2.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
                if (hittestinfo != null & NumberOfRequestProcess > 0)
                {
                    IndexRowsGR2 = hittestinfo.RowIndex;

                    /* && hittestinfo.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.RowHeader
                     * var ActiveCell = Component.dataGridView2[hittestinfo.ColumnIndex, hittestinfo.RowIndex];       
                      ActiveCell.Selected = true;
                     contextMenu.Show(Component.dataGridView2, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                     */
                }   
        }
```

Comment: @SergD29, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Я так понял, что у Вас, когда вызывается контекстное меню, не выбирается текущая ячейка, в которой щелкнули кнопкой???
Попробуйте добавить:

```
private void dataGridView2_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.ColumnIndex < dataGridView2.ColumnCount &&
      e.RowIndex < dataGridView2.RowCount)
  {
    dataGridView2.CurrentCell = dataGridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Это в любом случае уже не актуально, но у вас в условии бинарный оператор (&) вместо логического (&&). Начните с этого.